# Why Windows is being run in Hyper-V when it is enabled?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Microsoft is releasing Windows 10 with WSL 2 today, it seems like WSL 2 requires Hyper-V, so I've got a couple of questions:

From Hyper-V web page:

> In addition, if you have Hyper-V enabled, those latency-sensitive,
>   high-precision applications may also have issues running in the host.
>   This is because with virtualization enabled, the host OS also runs on
>   top of the Hyper-V virtualization layer, just as guest operating
>   systems do. However, unlike guests, the host OS is special in that it
>   has direct access to all the hardware, which means that applications
>   with special hardware requirements can still run without issues in the
>   host OS.

So, my main question is: **Why are they running Windows host on top of the Hyper-V virtualization layer?**

My understanding is that it comes with a series of inconveniences, like VirtualBox is not working, I saw some comments from people who managed to make it work but performance was bad.

Is there a noticeable difference for those who run CPU/GPU/SSD intensive apps?

Comment: It's not like Windows has a choice. When Hyper-V is enabled, **everything** runs in a VM, even the host operating system. That's why it's a hypervisor.

Comment: "everything runs in a VM", I know, and my question is - Why is it this way?

Comment: There is a "super operating system" called the hypervisor. All other operating systems run in VMs controlled by the hypervisor. The hypervisor has to work this way because the x86 processor is not self-virtualizing.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Hm, VirtualBox also has hypervisor but it does not require to run your host OS in it. Sorry my ignorance, I am really trying to understand :)

Comment: @Pavel , it's because there are two types of hypervisors: Type 1, also called "bare metal" hypervisors, of which Hyper-V is an example, and Type 2, which run within a host OS, of which VirtualBox is an example. This article sums it up really well: https://medium.com/teamresellerclub/type-1-and-type-2-hypervisors-what-makes-them-different-6a1755d6ae2c